# gcc version 4.6.1 is compatible with protobuf?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, czmq

I am using protobuf with zmq for one of my project. Can I use protobuf with this gcc version 4.6.1?

If yes, please let me know which version of protobuf I have to use.

Regards,
Smiley

Comment: GCC 4.6.1 is too old, it's better to use a modern one.

Answer (score 2):

According to [gh-issue](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2780) it requires c++11, so at least  `4.8.1` ([gcc c++ support](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)) would be required as it was first release feature-complete.